# Parse Push Notfications in MonoDroid

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, xamarin, parse-platform

So I'm using the Parse component from the Xamarin store in my MonoDroid app. So I was able to use the following code to store an object

```
ParseClient.Initialize ("appid", "windowskey");

var obj = new ParseObject("Note");
obj ["text"] = "Hello, world!  This is a Xamarin app using Parse!";
obj ["tags"] = new List<string> {"welcome", "xamarin", "parse"};
obj.SaveAsync ();
```

My real goal is to be able to do push notifications. Even though the above object stored, Parse did not register the device in the installations to be able to send push notifications. What else am I missing. Note: I'm doing this in the emulator but if i'm not mistaken it still should work.

Comment: Push notification support for Xamarin apps in Parse is not available right now.

Comment: @darrellbooker, did you find some sort of workaround?  I think the solution is to create a binding, which I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: @WilliamGrand did you find any work around ?

Answer (score 0):

@basit-zia, yes I did!  I had to create a binding for the push library from the Java Parse SDK.  I believe I was able to strip away all the libraries except for the necessary elements. I can't remember exactly what I did though.

Then in the Main Activity class, I put the following into the OnStart() method:

```
            // check for a notification
            if (Intent != null)
                try {
                string jsonString = Intent.Extras.GetString("com.parse.Data");
                PushObject jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PushObject>(jsonString);

                if (jsonObj.alert != null) {
                    Toast.MakeText (BaseContext, jsonObj.alert, ToastLength.Long).Show ();
                }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("JSONException: " + e.Message);
                }
```

And put the following into the OnCreate() method:

```
            Com.Parse.Parse.Initialize(this, "app id here"}, "client key here");
            PushService.SetDefaultPushCallback (this, this.Class);
            PushService.StartServiceIfRequired (this);
            ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation.SaveInBackground ();
```

Comment: Can you please share the binding library or dll? Thank you :)

Comment: Sure, here is a link to the binding.  I created it a year ago in November 2013, so it is a bit old: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16753475/ParseDroidBinding.dll

Comment: @WilliamGrand are you able to post the project you used to generate the dll, so we can use it against the latest parse build?

Comment: A year later and this is still an issue! @WilliamGrand could you please share the dll some other way? I'm getting a 403 error on dropbox.

Comment: Here is an updated DropBox link to the DLL: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4cpc60tl124lz5/ParseDroidBinding.dll?dl=0

Comment: @WilliamGrand Any chance you would throw the binding project up on github?