# Sending and Receiving information from Android using Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This is probably a silly question, but I'm very new to Android Development, and can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I'm making an app that will be installed on 3 devices, my personal Android, my brother's Android, and my Android Tablet. The app has variables for when we let the dog in, when we let him out, how long it's been since he's been in/out, etc.

I want the app to send updated information to the other 2 devices when a variable is changed, for example, when the dog is let out, the string that is displayed in the UI is changed.

How do I send the different strings to each device over Wifi/Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing that easy way to achieve what you want is to send notifications between apps using Internet is "Push Notifications".

There is serivce named: www.parse.com

You can find push notifications sdk for native Android app.
You can try to link to native library.

Please look here:

[Parse Push Notfications in MonoDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550261/parse-push-notfications-in-monodroid)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was even better than anything I had expected!